# Trouble understanding resulting bode plot while getting hands on filter design

Tags: filter, low-pass, remote-control

Recently tried to get hands on filter design, I tried to design à simple low-pass RC filter as shown here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9N9tN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Cutoff frequency must be \$\frac{1}{(2\pi\times47\times73\times10^-9)}=46.387kHz\$.

I made the circuit on breadboard as shown in the picture below.
Each coaxial plug is inserted on 3 lines, top and bottom line are ground and middle line is signal. Top left is the "in" signal and bottom right one is "out". So on the picture below, lines 3, 5 and 7 are ground. The resistor is plugged from line 4 to 6, and capacitor from line 6 to 7. To sum up signal enter line 4 from coaxial plug, goes to line 6 through the resistor, higher frequencies get out through capacitor, lower frequencies get out through the down right coaxial plug line 6.

[image: photography of breadboard circuit]

After properly calibrating the nanoVNA network analyser, this is what I get.

[image]

S21 is through signal (yellow)
S11 is reflected signal (blue)

The range pictured is from 1.6kHz to 55 kHz and the scale is 10dB per horizontal division.

First, I dont understand why the signal raise up to +5.17dB. When I short cables I get 0dB.

I dont understand why the signal goes down to -3.7dB (after the drop) at 24.562kHz instead of 46.387kHz

And the most confusing thing, I dont understand why I dont get a ramp that keeps going down at cutoff frquency. On higher frequencies, the signal remains at -3.7dB.

I checked that the resistor and the capacitor legs dont touch coaxial mass, I checked the cables. I have a minor doubt on capacitor, I read "7330" on one side and assumed a 733 code. I also tired to plug the whole circuit elsewhere on the breadboard.

Comment: The resistor looks like it is plugged 3 to 6 not 4 to 6.

Comment: No, it is barely visible on the picture, but its bent before the 3rd line hole, to the line 4.

Comment: You do not know the output resistance of your signal generator. It adds to your 47 ohms resistor. You also do not know the resistance of the load.

Comment: I must admit that the combination of RF connectors (SMA in your case) and breadboard is most amusing to me. In the kHz range, where breadboard would be permissible, you really don't benefit at all from RF connectors, and in the RF range, you can forget about using this type of breadboard right away.

Comment: also, I'm pretty sure that the nanoVNA is by no means designed to go down to 1.6 kHz. I think its useful analog frequency range starts at 50 kHz, and *that* is already a stretch.

Comment: [image of device back](https://static.eleshop.nl/mage/media/catalog/product/cache/10/thumbnail/1920x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/d/s/dsc05902-removebg.jpg) your measurement device goes nowhere near the frequencies you're trying to measure. Wrong device, or wrong frequencies to work at. But if you're working on breadboard, you really can't go much higher than 500 kHz.